# Session_id is beeing changed when page refresh

Tags: php, session, ini

I have problem about `session_id()` is beeing changing every page refresh.

Actually im using this function of session:

```
function sec_session_start()
{
   $session_name = 'sec_session_id'; 
   $secure = false; 
   $httponly = true; 
   ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); 
   $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
   session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"],
    $secure, $httponly);
   session_name($session_name); 
   session_start(); 
   session_regenerate_id(false); 
}
```

On every page im using

```
    include "function.php";
    sec_session_start();
```

so im doubting on this function because if i just use `session_start();` the `session_id()` doesnt change. it stays the same , how ever if i call the session from that function `sec_session_start()` the `session_id()` changes.

what is wrong with that function ? i couldnt find whats going wrong. all my website is using `sec_session_start()` so i cant change to `session_start()`.

any help much apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: session_regenerate_id() generates new session id as it's purpose.

Comment: False only to not delete the old session file. It's duty is creating a new session id.

Comment: no , false to not regenerate new id.

Comment: I mean. If false is used then your session vars will be kept but session I'd will be still changed.

Comment: yes its used false and its changed anyway , thats why my problem

Comment: session_regenerate_id() will change the session id no matter parameter you pass with it. Parameter is not about the id. More info in php manual.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer:

in fact

```
 session_regenerate_id(false);
```

was generating the new session id even thought it saids ***false***.

so what i done is just comment that line of `session_regenerate_id(false);` and everything works.

hope this will help some people .

Thanks to smozguurs suggestion.

Comment: Odd that the function should do exactly as the name suggests